# Prove that $(0,1) \subseteq\mathbb R$ and $(4,10) \subseteq\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've looked at a few examples on here of how cardinality works and I'm still struggling. This is the problem that I'm currently struggling with. I know there needs to be a bijection function. I'm just stuck on how to actually do it.

Comment: **Hint**: try a map in the for $g(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: Hint: What's the equation of a line that goes from $(0,4)$ to $(1,10)$?

Comment: y=(9/4)x +1 is what the equation should be

Comment: @Todd Bejamin: No. $y = \frac{9}{4} x + 1$ runs through $(0, 1)$ and $(4, 10)$, not the points indicated by John Douma.

Comment: Then what Egor said, y= 4 + 6x

Answer (score 0):

We need some monotonic function with domain $(0;1)$ and support $(4;10)$, it will definitely be bijection. Obvious candidate is $y = 4 + 6x$, make sure you can find another ones.